# Ionic cordova Hybrid application not creating using below command

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Hi I am very new for Hybrid application development and I have seen some tutorials which are related to hybrid application development and finally I started to create my First application using below command but I am getting the error bellow.

Can some one help me please?

### Command:-

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>ionic start sampleApp blank
```

### Error:-

```
× Creating directory .\sampleApp - failed!
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\sampleApp'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try another directory, it seems like you have no rights to create a new folder in the `nodejs` folder. You could use your documents directory for example or some other user directory.

If you really want to use the `nodejs` directory (*not recommended*), you need administration permissions for your console.

Comment: Exactly, that is probably the best place to keep your ionic projects. I add your advice to the answer. Thank you.

Comment: E:\HybridApps>ionic cordova platform add android.

Comment: when i use above command shows me errror like --->[ERROR] Sorry! ionic cordova platform can only be run in an Ionic project directory.

Comment: can you please help me what is the problem?

Comment: Can you please wrap your comments into one? You need to call `ionic start appName blank` before you can call any other ionic commands in your directory.

Comment: E:\HybridApps\sampleApp>ionic cordova platform add android.

Comment: √ Creating .\www directory for you - done!
> cordova platform add android. --save

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Using cordova-fetch for android.

Comment: but in project dictinary platform folder not showing android folder

Comment: **Again**! Please put your 5 comments into one. Do not spam the comment section. You can edit and delete your comments above. Related to the problem, the error message tells you exactly what to do.